# Add Buttons to TableRow Dynamically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Hello I want to click a button that will add a new button to a table row every time it is clicked. After 3 buttons have been added to the row, I want to dynamically create a new table row and add a new button to it.

I know how to add a row with a button(s) to a tableLayout if I click a button. I don't know how to modify the table row every time I click so I can add an additional button.

Any advice would be quite helpful and appreciated.

Following is my code but this is not perfect

```
public class DynamicTableView extends Activity {

    TableLayout mTlayout;
    String[] mTextofButton = { "Dipak", "E", "I", "J", "L",
            "M", "G", "R", "N", "T", "H", "P",
            "K", "Y", "V" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mTlayout);


        TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
        for(int i=0;i<mTextofButton.length;i++){
            Button btn=new Button(this);
            btn.setText(mTextofButton[i]);
            tr.addView(btn);

        }   
        mTlayout.addView(tr);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem? Looks like your code should work.

Comment: My code is work but button is added dynamically & see above description of my problem. how to add only 3 buttons in one row and then create next tablerow.

Comment: looks like you have problems with **simple** codeflow ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use following Code:-

```
public class DynamicButtonsActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout mTlayout;
    TableRow tr;
    String[] mTextofButton = { "D", "E", "I", "J", "L", "M", "G", "R", "N",
            "T", "H", "P", "K", "Y", "V" };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTlayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mTlayout);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < mTextofButton.length) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                tr = new TableRow(this);
                mTlayout.addView(tr);
            }
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(mTextofButton[i]);
            btn.setId(i);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("v.getid is:- " + v.getId());
                }
            });
            tr.addView(btn);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<mTextofButton.length){
            if(i%3==0){
                TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
                mTlayout.addView(tr);
            }
            Button btn=new Button(this);
            btn.setText(mTextofButton[i]);
            tr.addView(btn);
            i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

their would a `Button`'s `onClick()`, say `addNewButton()` and do something like this:

```
public void  addNewButton(View b)
{
        for(int i=0; i<mTextofButton.length; i+=3){
                TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);

                Button btnOne=new Button(this);
                btnOne.setText(mTextofButton[i]);
                tr.addView(btnOne);

                Button btnTwo =new Button(this);
                btnTwo.setText(mTextofButton[i+1]);
                tr.addView(btnTwo);

                Button btnThree =new Button(this);
                btnThree.setText(mTextofButton[i+2]);
                tr.addView(btnThree);
                mTlayout.addView(tr);
        }
}
```

but be careful about your `mTextofButton.length`, means it should divisable by 3 otherwise you gonna getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBondException`. better method is to use `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: I am adding 3 buttons in one row and then create next table row but my question is "how to do it?"

Comment: Your Code is Working but how to create listener for dynamic buttons.

Comment: look for .setOnClickListener(...)

Comment: @biovamp: why did you delete your answer. that was nice answer.. you know what, I was going to delete this one.